# Creating a list of nodes attached to each node (c++)

Tags: c++, arrays, object, constructor, adjacency-list

I am trying to create each node with a pointer to an array that will contain other nodes (of the same type) within the object's class.

```cpp
class node
{
public:
    node(int degree, bool visited, int xpos, int ypos);
    node *adjList = new node[9]; 
    float * valueList = new float[832];
    int size = 0;
    int adjSize = 0;
    int xpos, ypos;
    int degree = 0;
    bool visited;
};
```

The line is

```cpp
node *adjList = new node[9];
```

This does not work. It is saying there is no matching constructor for this declaration. I tried creating an empty constructor but that sort of breaks my code.

The visualization is this:

NODE:
[0] ---> [ [3][4]][8] ]

Comment: That's right. `new node[9]` creates nine `node` objects and ***default construct*** them. The problem is that there's no `node` default constructor.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
   node *adjList = new node[9];
```

creates creates nine `node` objects and tries to default construct each of them, since you don't have a default constructor in your `node` class, the compiler complains. Just add a default constructor to your `node` class:

```
class node
{

   public:

       node(int degree, bool visited, int xpos, int ypos);

       node(); //Default ctor

       node *adjList = new node[9]; 
       float * valueList = new float[832];
       int size = 0;
       int adjSize = 0;
       int xpos, ypos;
       int degree = 0;
       bool visited;
};
```